# NoClassDefFoundError: StoppedByUserException with Eclipse and Quick JUnit

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, quick-junit

Eclipse with Quick JUnit plugin gives the me following error when I try to run a JUnit test with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/notification/StoppedByUserException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.notification.StoppedByUserException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

JUnit is in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse plugin (which disappeared during a previous Eclipse upgrade) fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by installing Ive DE. The problem was basically dependencies not being resolved. 
I did not notice until running Junit as the project was already compiled with an older eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found this may be due to opening an eclipse mars workspace with eclipse luna. I did that and couldn't get it to work until i remembered that I had updated eclipse but not the link to eclipse. opening with eclipse mars all unit tests worked again.